# Evaluating IIS7 with Virtual PC?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, evaluation, windows-server, vhd

I wanna do some local developer tests of IIS 7 but I don't have Windows Vista, 7 or 2008 server - I currently run XP SP3.

I have Virtual PC installed so I can use Microsoft's IE compatibility images - are there any time-limited images that I can use with Virtual PC so I can check out IIS 7?

The IIS 7 "Try it" link points to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx). But the VHS is for Windows Server platforms only I think and I don't want an ISO?

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the 180-day trial of Windows Server from that same page.

This will give you a file called an ISO image, which is a complete image of a CD.
After downloading it, you can mount the ISO image in Virtual PC and install Windows Server onto a virtual machine.  (You don't need to burn a physical CD)

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't specify, I would expect [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=27d91e63-e33b-4cef-a331-f20d343da9de&displaylang=en) to run Windows 7. Also, it says that it's for "Virtual PC for Windows 7" but I would be surprised if it didn't run under WinXP. Unfortunately, I don't have any physical WinXP boxes anymore (and I'm not going to try running Virtual PC on a VM - that will probably cause problems itself that will complicate this).

Comment: I don't think it will run in XP. Windows Virtual PC for Windows 7 is substantially different from VPC 2007.

Comment: Really?? You learn something new every day! I've actually yet to run Virtual PC on Win7, everything is Hyper-V anymore except for legacy ESXi and VMWare Server images. And at home my Virtual PC hosts are still running Vista because I've not gotten around to updating that. Sorry @Neil if I pointed you in the wrong direction. Maybe @SLaks's idea of going with a clean install is your best bet.